# What formula can I use to insert x number of rows, where x is the difference between two textbox responses?

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I am creating a userform that is going to form a report template for the user.

The template needs to have a certain number of rows based on the "Start Date" and "End Date" reported by the user. The number of rows added will be "Start Date" minus "End Date" plus 1.

I currently have only figured out the below code by copying a recorded macro:

```
    Worksheets(5).Rows("5:27").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

In the above code I can leave 5, as it will always be the place of the start dates row. However the 27 needs to be a variable.

Is it possible to enter a variable into the Rows range that can insert a changing number of rows (based off a function)? Is there another code that I should be using?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

And advice on what names I should be using to describe certain things would be helpful as well. I am a beginner with VBA and do not know syntax too well.

**EDIT: ADDITIONAL QUESTIONS**

Thanks @findwindow I created the DateDiff function in a module so i get the number of rows needed. Function is below.

```
Function NumberofRows(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date)  
NumberofRows = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2) + 1
End Function
```

I am trying to return the answer from the function into the code below. I am getting an error "Type Mismatch". Are you able to tell me what I am coding wrong or if there is an easier way to do this. "SDI" and "EDI" are named cells that contain the Start dates and End dates.

```
Private Sub InsertRows()
Dim i As Integer
i = NumberofRows("SDI", "EDI")

Worksheets(5).Rows("5:" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown,
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

The above code is entered into the Userform, I have 
    Call.InsertRows
within another sub that corresponds to a command button click.

Thank you so much!!!

EDIT 2: 
Also, looking at this. I believe I have to find a way for the NumberofRows output to determine which row variable 'i' should actually be, not just i itself. I guess it would be 'i+5' since that is the starting row? or probably just change the NumberofRows function to DateDiff("d",x,x)+6?

Comment: Set i to the difference between the start and end date plus 1 then do `WorkSheets(5).Rows("5:" & i).Insert`

Comment: Thanks @findwindow. I created the function that I am trying to return to the code below that. I am getting an error "Type Mismatch". Are you able to tell me what I am coding wrong or what I should be doing instead.

Comment: Function NumberofRows(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long

      NumberofRows = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2) + 1

     End Function

Comment: Private Sub InsertRows()

Dim i As Long
i = NumberofRows("SDI", "EDI")

    Worksheets(5).Rows("5:" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub

Comment: Don't know how to enter these in the code format, sorry. I am a noob.. :/

Comment: Please edit your OP and use the code block tag.

Comment: @findwindow done, thanks for your help. doing this for work.

Comment: @findwindow resolved the issue. Sorry about all these posts/notifications. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the value of a named range to your function, so you need to pass them from your sub as range objects rather than dates - or strings which is what they were going through as hence the type mismatch.

Then on your calculation of how to work out how many rows to insert, you need to add the value of i to your lower row number to get the number of your upper row so you're selecting all rows within.

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub InsertRows()
Dim i As Integer
i = NumberofRows(Range("SDI"), Range("EDI"))

Worksheets(5).Rows("5:" & 5 + i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

and

```
Function NumberofRows(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date)
NumberofRows = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Did this help? Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.